# Determine if generated type is value-type

Tags: c#, codedom

I have some types created via CodeDOM. Is there a way to determine if a type of a given property is a value-type?

For those declared within mscorlib it´s pretty easy as I can call `Type.GetType` and then check for `Type.IsValueType`. However for those types within my DOM we can´t use this approach as there´s no assembly to load the types from.

```
var codeType = code.Types[0].Members[0];
bool isValueType = // get the runtime-type to determine if it is value-type or not
```

Answer (score 0):

The `CodeTypeDeclaration.IsStruct` property, despite its name, does exactly this — determines whether the type is a value type. See the documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.codetypedeclaration.isstruct(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Sorry, I mis-wrote the question, you´re right, this property exists on `CodeTypeDeclaration`. However I need to know the type of a **property** within that type.